# passing metadata on when adding track using Webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've looked at pretty much all the solutions on SO going from using `getSettings().deviceId` or even retrieving the `id` of the stream but none really worked or matches my use case.

I need to pass on both ends metadata like device's name, device's id and even more. Is it possible to pass in metadata with tracks using webRTC video/audio channels?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.

If you control the signalling server, then the simplest solution is to include the metadata together with the offer/answer message that you send through it.  If the metadata applies to the whole stream, that's all there is to it.

If, however, you need to send per-track metadata, then you need to be aware that the track label is not preserved across the network.  The ordering of tracks within a stream, however, is preserved, so you may index your metadata by the index of the track (the *mid*).